# Display only LOWER levels of chapters/sections in TOC using \setcounter{tocdepth}?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a question about the table of contents: I know that, e.g., `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` can be used if I want to, only display parts, chapters and sections in the table of contents and supress subsections and below.

My question, however, is if the opposite is possible - for example ONLY displaying sections and lower levels and not showing parts and chapters. Using `\section*` or equivalent is not an option in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is wrong with the starred command `\chapter*`, `\part*`? Or do you _need_ the numbering? (Though numbered but not in the TOC seems rather strange...)

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on the class, but with book you can e.g. do

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{}`  will also suppress the sections.

Answer (score 2):

With a **KOMA-Script class** you can change the style of ToC entries to `gobble` using

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocstyle=gobble]{part,chapter}
```

or

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{gobble}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{gobble}{chapter}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocstyle=gobble]{part,chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

With a **standard class** you can use

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level=-1]{gobble}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level=0]{gobble}{chapter}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level=-1]{gobble}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level=0]{gobble}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\part{a part}
\chapter{a chapter}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\end{document}
```